# How to remove duplicate results from BLAST?

Tags: blast

If I run BLAST using a protein sequence (e.g. human p53), I get many matches to the same protein, presumably from different research projects. As you can see from the screenshot, all are similarly named and close to exact matches. Is there any way I can filter the results to get unique genes only?

[image: p53 BLAST results]

Comment: imagine, you can. then how do you want to pick those that are "unique"? What makes one accession number better than another for same protein? my point is that those are all a bit different, but all as real as the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose reference protein as a database. Then you can avoid the same sequence from different projects. 
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/about/

Answer (score 2):

BLAST against a non-redundant database (for e.g. `nr` and [UniProt](http://www.uniprot.org/help/redundancy)). `nr` contains all non-redundant sequences collected from different primary databases but nonetheless [there **is** some redundancy](https://www.biostars.org/p/55068/). You can also specify (or filter out) the species if you are not interested in all species.

Finally, you can also choose the best hit (post-BLAST, using simple scripts).

Comment: My point is that those results are already from the `nr` database, and are nevertheless all the same protein from the same species but with different accession numbers.